# how to send data to client with expressJS

Tags: node.js, express, backend

How would I go into retrieving data from expressJS? That is without it getting overwritten, or redirecting a user.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Retrieved data</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

for example how would i go into adding it if the server side looks like this?

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
    //how do i add data to the <h1> tag
});

app.listen(10022, function () {
    console.log("server is up");
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You wouldn't be able to do it with a .html file. You'd need an EJS file. The markup for that would look like this.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Retrieved <%= data %></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then you'll need the ejs module. Run the following NPM command.

`npm install ejs`

So change your index.html to index.ejs, make sure it's in a directory named `views`, and then modify your server side code to this.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
        res.render("index", {data: 'This is the data'});
});

app.listen(10022, function () {
        console.log("server is up");
});
```

EJS is a templating language that converts to HTML, taking the data object you've passed in through your render method, rendering it server side, and then sending it to the browser.

Comment: this probably will work. so thank you :D but if you don't mind me asking why does it need to be in a dir named views why can't it be different?

Comment: No problem! Express looks there by default to lookup views to render. I'm pretty sure there's a way to change that, but I don't know it off the top of my head.

Comment: Are templating engines the only way to send data along with an HTML file?

Comment: Sort of.They're one of several methods to customise a generic html form to include more specific user data. You could use React server side rendering to do the same thing, although I suppose that's also a templating engine. Otherwise, you can send data in a json, in a different call, and let the front end take care of displaying it.

Comment: Is there anyway of not using ejs? Just sending to data to JavaScript and having it handle it? For example, the above comment mentioned JSON